# How to build in 64 bit using Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2005 for C++ projects. I want to build this project in 64 bits. But there is no option in configuration manager. How I can build this in 64? It need to be built in Visual studio 2005.

Comment: 64-bit compilers were an install option in VS2005.  So you probably didn't turn that option on.  Rerun setup and reapply the service pack.

Answer (score 2):

Setup VS 2005 -> Repair -> + in C++ Components - check the box x64 Tools

Answer (score 0):

In project Properties > Linker > Advanced > Target Machine, choose "MachineX64"